# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout error in GKE pod

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

While running kubectl get pods command in GKE pod, we are getting the following error frequently. Some times, when started 2 pods(deployment) on 2 nodes, on one pod, the command executes successfully and on another pod, the command gives the following error on the another pod on the same docker image:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

We are getting the following error while running pods(chaos-mesh master controller:chaos-controller-manager-d945b5d5b-f2pr7) in GKE as well, looks similar to above:

```
"error": "Get "https://10.0.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout"}
Failed to get API Group-Resources {"error": "Get "https://10.0.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout"}
```

Can any one suggest any solution to it. As you know google doesn't provide any support for pay as you go. This puts us in very difficult situation, even we pay, but we don;t get support. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### This can occur when kubectl is unable to talk to the cluster control plane.

[To resolve this issue, set the cluster context using the following command:](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubectl-times-out)

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME [--region=REGION | --zone=ZONE]
```

If you are unsure of what to enter for CLUSTER_NAME, use the following command to list your clusters:

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

I hope this information is useful to resolve your issue.